# decltype on an element of std::vector

Tags: c++11, decltype

Why does the following not compile?

```
  std::vector<int> v{1,2};
  decltype(v[0]) i;           //doesn't work
  decltype(v)::value_type j;  //works
```

I receive the error `test.cpp:31:18: error: declaration of reference variable 'i' requires an initializer`. Isn't `v[0]` of type `int` here?

I understand that even if it did work, it wouldn't be as safe as the latter in case the vector is empty, but I feel that should be a runtime issue rather than a compile time issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decltype(v[0])` yields you the type of expression `v[0]` which is a reference to the element (unless `v` is `vector<bool>`). A reference variable must be initialized, and that is what the compiler error message says.

You can use `auto` to get an element by value and `auto&` to get it by reference:

```
auto element = v[0];
auto& element_ref = v[0];
```

Comment: In this case `decltype(v[0])` yields `int &`? That's interesting. I thought it would work like `auto` and templating where the reference is not deduced.

Comment: @Iamanon See point 4 in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

Comment: `auto` uses standard template deduction rules (i.e. never deduce a reference), whereas `decltype` uses different rules.

Comment: I see now. I was under the impression that it used the same rules.